# Where is the H2O Driverless AI license file (license.sig)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, h2o, snowflake-schema

I am working through this lab, where a H2O Driverless AI model is trained, and deployed to Snowflake. I used Snowflake Partner Connect to set up a 7 day trial of H2O Driverless AI.

https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/automl_with_snowflake_and_h2o/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Everything went smoothly until the last step, to deploy the model to Snowflake, where a license.sig file from H20 is needed. All it says is:

> Last, you will need your Driverless AI license file license.sig

However I cannot find this file, nor any instructions about where to find it or download it.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/1-8-lts/docs/userguide/licenses.html) helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Azim from H2O.ai.

To deploy the model you trained on your H2O DAI instance and start making predictions, you will need a license key. As a trial user, you could sign up here for a license key that is valid for 21 days: https://www.h2o.ai/try-driverless-ai/

This is listed as a prerequisite in the first section titled `Use Case Overview` on the Snowflake and H2O.ai quickstart guide. Thanks for your question, we will clarify this by adding a note on the `Deployment` section too.

Should you have any further questions, please feel free to reach out to me directly and I'd be happy to help: h2o.snowflake@h2o.ai, azim.baghadiya@h2o.ai